# Python - psycopg2.sql – calling function

Tags: python, postgresql, function, psycopg2

I try to call substring function in dynamic SQL.

```
from psycopg2 import sql as ps_sql

sql = ps_sql.SQL('select {}').format(ps_sql.Identifier("substring('TEST',1,2)"))
with db.conn_ogis.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

I have error: psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "substring('TEST',1,2)" doesn't exixst

How can I call function properly?

Comment: sql = ps_sql.SQL('select {} from nazwa_tabeli  ').format(
    ps_sql.SQL(', ').join(ps_sql.Identifier(n) for n in ["user", "substring(host,1,2)", "password"]))
I want to join list of columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Identifier()` function only for Postgres identifiers (i.e. names of a table, column, view, function etc). So you could use it this way:

```
sql = ps_sql.SQL("select {}('TEST',1,2)").format(ps_sql.Identifier("substring"))
```

Actually, in this particular case the identifier `substring` does not need quoting (because it is in lowercase):

```
sql = ps_sql.SQL("select substring('TEST',1,2)")
```

Comment: I have to build a list of column after select. Some of them use substring but some not. I try to build construction to do it.

Comment: This description tells me nothing. I cannot guess what is the real problem. Show this as an example in the question.

Comment: sql = ps_sql.SQL('select {} from nazwa_tabeli  ').format(
    ps_sql.SQL(', ').join(ps_sql.Identifier(n) for n in ["user", "substring(host,1,2)", "password"]))
I want to join list of columns

Comment: This cannot be done with `Identifier()`. If all column names are in lowercase you can replace `Identifier` with `SQL` in your query.